# Offline iOS app that gives the full declensions of German nouns

Tags: ios, dictionary

I had an app that worked offline using the Wiktionary database, but iOS 11 broke it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try one of the following apps for IOS. These three seem to have the best ratings. There are of course several others, which you can find in the IOS app store.

**Learn German Nouns Der Die Das**
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/learn-german-nouns-der-die-das/id646652757?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

**German English Dictionary +**
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/german-english-dictionary/id568041778?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

**Learn German - 3,400 words**
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/learn-german-3-400-words/id598993528?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

Comment: The closest to what i'm looking for is Der, Die Das but it only gives the gender of nouns, not the declensions for all cases for all nouns. The other is a dictionary which I already have but doesn't decline nouns. I've looked everywhere and maybe none exists now.

Answer (score 0):

The Canoonet app is the only German app I could find that declines nouns but it's relatively expensive (around $8 U.S. or 150 pesos)